# Validating parameters in a provided callback function in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript, functional-programming

I don't think this is possible, but is there a way to validate the arguments a callback accepts.  For example someone passes me callback "mycallback", I want to assert it accepts an argument String.

```
public function addHandler(handler : Function) : void{
    //pseudo code 
    Assert.functionAcceptsArguments(handler, String);
 }
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. If you had some object as argument you could use `describeType` which returns information about methods too. But `Function` is just a function with no information about arguments.

To be sure that you get right method signature you could pass typed objects not Functions. For example

```
interface Bla {
  funciton invoke(value:String):void;
}

function addHandler(handler:Bla):void {}
```